# Route domain in Apache

Tags: apache

I have domain for my site which is located on *Azure Linux* server. Problem is - domain in routed on *IP* address directly and when I visit `"www.example.com"` I getting *Apache* page. 
My site is located in `IpAddress/example`. How can I route access from `"www.example.com"` to open page located in `/example` on *Apache*. This is my first contact with domains, sorry for basic question.

Comment: Change the server root directory to your desired directory and all the unhandled requests will be served from there

Comment: But if I have multiple website hosted? I want to route it:  www.example1.com to be routed on /example1  etc.

Comment: Then you can simply create as many vhosts as you like. Google is filled with results for that

Comment: Moderator can lock this one, I think I made it with vhosts. Thank you @HankyPanky and thanks all others. ;)

Answer (score 0):

move your `'example'` folder to up one level and make sure you override index.html with your application's landing page.

Comment: I used virtual host and I think I solved it. 
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        <Directory "/var/www/html/example">
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

And it works good I guess